# How to check if ActiveMQ is working properly?

Tags: activemq-classic

What would be the simplest way to test if ActiveMQ is functioning properly?

Would it be by putting a message in a queue and remove from the queue?

Say with a programming language like python? Or would there be simpler methods that already do this?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go some practical examples on how to do so in ActiveMQ 5:

Via Jolokia REST API (requiring authentication):

```bash
curl -u admin:admin -H origin:localhost http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,service=Health/CurrentStatus | grep Good
```

Or via `activemq` CLI directly (useful for creating docker health checks):

```bash
/opt/activemq/bin/activemq query --objname type=Broker,brokerName=*,service=Health | grep Good
```

Both were tested using [symptoma/activemq:5.17.2](https://hub.docker.com/r/symptoma/activemq) docker image.

Plus: Health check using docker-compose:

```yaml
services:
  activemq:
    image: symptoma/activemq:5.17.2
    ports:
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/activemq/bin/activemq query --objname type=Broker,brokerName=*,service=Health | grep Good
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

Comment: `/opt/activemq/bin/activemq status` also works

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ exposes management functions via JMX which you can use from GUI tools like JVisualVM and JConsole (among others).  One of these exposed MBeans provides "health" information (i.e. `HealthViewMBean`).  You can read more about this in the [ActiveMQ wiki](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html).

Testing the health of the broker by sending/receiving a message is certainly possible and not terribly difficult. In general, I think the simplest method would be to use [the command-line tools](http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-examples.html) available in the ActiveMQ distribution.  If you're using Python then you could write a simple application that produces a message and then consumes it using STOMP.  A good place to start on that would be [here](https://pythonhosted.org/stompy/introduction.html).

Comment: Or use JMX and connect to view the HealthViewMBean which can tell you what the server health is.

Comment: Good point.  I updated my answer to reflect your comment, Tim.