# ActiveMQ connection status check for health checks

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, health-check

I have 2 services that communicate with each other using ActiveMQ. In my service I want to implement the health check endpoint such that it checks the ActiveMQ for **available/valid** connection status. A similar example is with MongoDB checking the **readyState** of the connection.

Is there a solution for implementing such check?

Comment: Most messaging protocols have some kind of heart-beating/connection-validation mechanism built-in. What protocol are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if ActiveMQ is working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500782/how-to-check-if-activemq-is-working-properly)

Comment: You can find some practical examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74476450/2525895